# Cannot Retrieve a Single data from Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve the display name of the user from firebase database. But this code does not working.  Is there any wrong with my code? Please help me.

```
 Firestore.instance.collection('/users').where('email', isEqualTo: '${widget.user.email}')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) =>
    data.documents.forEach((doc)=>userName==(doc["displayName"]),));
```

Comment: Firstly if you want to read a data once...you don't need snapshots.... just use `Firestore.instance.collection('/users').where('email', isEqualTo: '${widget.user.email}').getDocuments()`... and also whats your firestore structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing there is a problem with assigning the value to `userName`. Try using:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('/users').where('email', isEqualTo: '${widget.user.email}')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) =>
    data.documents.forEach((doc)=>userName=(doc["displayName"]),));
```

Also, as @Ryosuke suggested, if you want to read data only once, you can use

```
Firestore.instance.collection('/users').where('email', isEqualTo: '${widget.user.email}')
.getDocuments().then((value){
value.documents.forEach((doc)=>userName=doc["displayName"]);
});
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if something went wrong.